# What is the difference between $translateChangeSuccess and $translateChangeStart .Which one should i use in my case?

Tags: angularjs, translation, angular-translate

```
  $rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function () {   
     A= $translate.instant('aaa');
     B= $translate.instant('bbb');  
     C= $translate.instant('ccc');    
});
```

What is the difference between $translateChangeSuccess and $translateChangeStart .Which one should i use when i want to translate both while loading the page and also while changing the language?

I want these A, B, C to get translated `on loading of the page and also while switching the language`.

If i use the above code, sometimes while loading this event is not getting fired and it is not getting translated.

So which will be the best way  to translate in this case?

If anyone knows please do help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As the name implies, `$translateChangeStart` is kicked of when the process is started, `$translateChangeSuccess` is kicked of when the process was succesful. It's all in [this documentation](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/18_events)

Comment: Okay.. My problem is i want a common function to execute in both ways.While starting the page and also while changing the language.@devqon

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use one function, split it in a separate function:

```
$rootScope.$on('$translateChangeStart', translate);
$rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', translate);

function translate() {
     A = $translate.instant('aaa');
     B = $translate.instant('bbb');  
     C = $translate.instant('ccc');    
}
```